# Is it correct to refer to the database when creating a Bean?

Tags: java, spring, architecture

The hardware configuration is stored in a database. Is it correct to make a method in the configuration that returns a Bean configured from the data obtained from the database? Or is it better not to use Bean and create such objects in code? Or is there another option?

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class ProtocolConfig {
    private final List<DecisionPointModel> decisionPointModels;
    String deviceAddress;

    public ProtocolConfig(DecisionPointRepository decisionPointRepository) {
        decisionPointModels = decisionPointRepository.findAll();
        Optional<DecisionPointModel> dpm = decisionPointModels.stream().findFirst();
        dpm.ifPresent(decisionPointModel -> deviceAddress = decisionPointModel.getControllerParameterModel().getDevice().getDeviceAddress());
    }

    @Bean
    public S7ProtocolMultiWrite multiResponseBean() {
        if (decisionPointModels.size() > 0) {
            int responseDb = S7Protocol.parseConnectionString(decisionPointModels.get(0).getControllerParameterModel().getCommandConnectionString()).getDb();
            Long countResponse = decisionPointModels.stream().count() * PlcResponseDataBlock.byteLength;
            return new S7ProtocolMultiWrite(deviceAddress, responseDb, countResponse.intValue());
        } else {
            throw new BeanCreationException("Error Creating multiResponseBean");
        }
    }

    @Bean(name = "arriveReadBean")
    public S7ProtocolMultiRead multiArriveBean() {
        if (decisionPointModels.size() > 0) {
            int arriveDb = S7Protocol.parseConnectionString(decisionPointModels.get(0).getControllerParameterModel().getArriveConnectionString()).getDb();
            Long countArrive = decisionPointModels.stream().count() * PlcRequestDataBlock.byteLength;
            return new S7ProtocolMultiRead(deviceAddress, arriveDb, countArrive.intValue());
        } else {
            throw new BeanCreationException("Error Creating multiArriveBean");
        }
    }

}
```